# I am not sure how to convert my webpages Table over to divs instead

Tags: html, css

I have this table on my website and I am wanting to switch it over to use divs instead but I am still working on studying HTML and am not sure how to go about it.  I have a css called theme.css and I know that somthing goes in it to cause this to work.

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td class="cellWidth">
             <img src="4-cute-cats.jpg" class="centerImage" width="300" height="300" />
             <p class="centerText">They hunt in packs.</p>
         </td>
         <td>

             <img src="cat_sniping.jpg" class="centerImage" width="256" height="192" />
             <p class="centerText">Sniper Cat</p></a>
         </td>
         <td class="cellWidth">
             <img src="LOL1.jpg" class="centerImage" width="300" height="298" />
             <p class="centerText">Sneaking Cat</p>
         </td>
         <td class="cellWidth">
             <img src="hammercat.jpg" class="centerImage" width="300" height="163" />
             <p class="centerText">80s Cat</p>
         </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="cellWidth">
             <img src="kittytrap.jpg" class="centerImage" width="200" height=492 />
             <p class="centerText">It's a trap!</p>
         </td>
         <td class="cellWidth">
             <img src="chop-cats.jpg" class="centerImage" width="300" height="140" />
             <p class="centerText">They can strip a car to the frame in under 2:00 minutes.</p>
         </td>
         <td class="cellWidth">
             <img src="smartkat.jpg" class="centerImage" width="200" height="338" />
             <p class="centerText">Intelligent cat.</p></a>
         </td>
         <td class="cellWidth">
             <img src="narniacat.jpg" class="centerImage" width="200" height="337" />
             <p class="centerText">Once a cat of Narnia always a cat of Narnia.</p>
         </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="cellWidth">
             <img src="lolcats3.jpg" class="centerImage" width="300" height="108" />
             <p class="centerText">Tired cat.</p>
         </td>
         <td class="cellWidth">
             <img src="lol_cats_1.jpg" class="centerImage" width="300" height="142" />
             <p class="centerText">Gollum Cat.</p>
         </td>
         <td class="cellWidth">
             <img src="Magical-Kitty.png" class="centerImage" width="300" height="180" />
             <p class="centerText">Super Cat.</p>
         </td>
         <td class="cellWidth">
             <img src="sad-kitty.jpg" class="centerImage" width="300" height="188" />
             <p class="centerText">Sad Kitty.</p>
         </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="cellWidth">
             <img src="cat-in-your-wallpaper.jpg" class="centerImage" width="300" height="200" />
             <p class="centerText">Wallpaper cat.
         </td>
         <td class="cellWidth">
             <img src="thinking-cat.jpg" class="centerImage" width="300" height="475" />
             <p class="centerText">Thinking cat.</p>
         </td>
         <td class="cellWidth">
             <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_znuneBeHigk/TSOOr5DuoQI/AAAAAAAABFY/-Rpe8S1uRo8/s1600/000.jpg&w=823&h=618&ei=_A4VUfP7L4Gy2QXJ-oHIDQ&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:79,s:0,i:354&iact=rc&dur=2621&sig=108293906633680688065&page=3&tbnh=172&tbnw=231&start=67&ndsp=38&tx=64&ty=72" class="centerImage" width="300" height="225" />
             <p class="centerText">Gamer Kitty.</p>
         </td>
         <td class="cellWidth">
             <img src="http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/funny-lol-cats-playing-with-toilet-paper1.jpg" class="centerImage" width="300" height="504" />
             <p class="centerText">Couch cat.</p>
         </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td align="center">
        <a href="morekitties.html">More Kitties</a>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This looks like tabular data. Why do you want to move away from tables?

Comment: I am trying to learn HTML and I am wanting to see how it works that way my friend told me you can take divs and do the exact some thing done in this table and I am wanting to see how that works.  Also latter the content is going to change over and I believe that the div format will end up more usefull during that point.

Comment: You've got a bunch of orphaned `</a>` tags and a missing `</p>` in that HTML up there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kLmpV/

Here is a starting point. See if you can understand this, and convert your table into a layout similar.

**html**

```
 <div class="wrapper">
        <article>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </article>

        <article>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </article>

        <article>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </article>

        <article>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </article>

        <article>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </article>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 1%;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 23%;
    position: relative;
    background: pink;
    margin: 1%;
}
```

Comment: This was extreemly helpfull I am a visual learner and it helped allot I have one question I posted my css at the top now what must I do to my css to keep it all looking the same.

Comment: update the jsFiddle with your your css and post the link here so I can take a look

Comment: Ok I am not sure what I am doing wrong here is a link to what it should look like http://dl.dropbox.com/u/65104705/Temp%20Web/index.html   And here is a link to jsfidlle of what my code looks like  http://jsfiddle.net/8WKR9/1/

Comment: im sorry, I have set you in the right direction, I cant do the work for you. Give it a shot, go further, if your stuck, again pose a new questions on the site. If you feel I deserve  the answer, dont forget ;). Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Have look at using framework like [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) it will help by giving you a base set of CSS to work with, making the transition a bit easier.

You html above isn't too wrong, the rule of thumb would be don't use tables for page layout (like your outer table) but its okay to use it for tabular data. (like lists of data)

Using the bootstrapframework.

You could easily change it to something like:

```
<div class="container"> <--- Would be in your base template

<div class="row">

 <div class="span8">
     <table>
      ... Your tabular data
     </table>
 </div>
 <div class="span4">
        <a href="morekitties.html">More Kitties</a>
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you break it down, the HTML code involves two tables nested within each other:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table> ... </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            ...
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This appears to control the layout, making sure that the inner table appears on the top, and the 'more kitties' link below.

This can be removed entirely:

```
<table> <!-- inner table --> </table>
<p class="centered"><a href="...">More Kitties</a></p>
```

Using css:

```
.centered {
    text-align: center; 
}
```

I would suggest leaving that inner table (the one with the cat pictures) as a table, since it is actually image data. ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fzK2N/))

---

If you really want to transform the inner table into `<div>`s, then I'd suggest the following:

1. Take every cell (`<td>`) and convert that to a `<div>`
2. Style each `<div>` with `display:inline-block;`. This will cause them to appear next to each other (inline) but still have explicit sizing (block).

See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qgCtx/) as an example. I only included the first two rows of cat pictures. Notice that the number of elements in each "row" depends on the available horizontal width and how wide each picture is. If you specify an explicit width on the wrapper, and explicit widths on the `<div>`s, then you can control how many appear in each row.

Another thing to remember is that the `inline-block` CSS property value won't work with the older IE browsers. (6 and 7, for certain. I'm not sure about IE8 support.)